# Objective-C: enforce call to super when overriding specific super methods in subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, super

We all know how easy it is to override a method in a subclass and forget to call `[super method]`.

In my case I have:

```
ClassA (framework class, can not be modified)
ClassB (my own class)
ClassC (user's subclass)
```

ClassA already provides a method `doSomething`. For sake of keeping the same API I have to override `doSomething` and require ClassC to call [super doSomething] should the user decide to implement her own version of `doSomething`.

Since this framework will also be used by beginners I wanted to know if there are ways to determine that a method has not called its super version, or where possibly even the compiler throws a warning/error when the user implements the method but doesn't call super.

I know that doing so is an anti-pattern. This is just to prevent user error because not calling super will result in issues that will not be easily pinned to a missing super call.

I also know the alternative would be to expose the user to a different API (ie `doCustomSomething`) yet I still couldn't prevent the user to simply override the original `doSomething` (out of habit) and thus bypassing any `doSomething` code added to ClassB. So this won't do.

I'm mainly looking for ways to notify the user of a missing [super doSomething] but if there are alternative ways to actually ensure doSomething of ClassB runs when its super class (ClassA) executes doSomething, that would work too. I'm guessing maybe some obscure method swizzling could do the trick (again, only to detect and throw an error)?